# Attacking multi block MAC constructions

Tags: mac, attack

> For variable-length messages, there are three different ways to generate the tags.
>
> 1. $Tag = MAC_k(\Sigma_i m_i)$.
> 2. $t_i = MAC_k(m_i)$ and $Tag = (t_1, ..., t_l)$.
> 3. $t_i = MAC_k(i||m_i)$ where $i$ is a sequence number and $Tag = (t_1, ..., t_l)$.
>
> Find an attack for each case.
>
> <sub>*Problem comes from Communication Systems Security, by Chen and Gong, [page 179](https://books.google.com/books?id=ooDV8MQiO_cC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22For+variable-length+messages,+there+are+three+different+ways+to+generate+the+tags.%22&source=bl&ots=POA9kT8ujd&sig=_JqrtkU69uLop7u5gS-7G5u2MQk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OYLaVOSlCYmMsQSy8YGgDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22For%20variable-length%20messages%2C%20there%20are%20three%20different%20ways%20to%20generate%20the%20tags.%22&f=false)*</sub>

I have been looking for various attacks for the above question. Can anyone help me with the answer?

Comment: You should explain what you have tried and where, specifically, you are stuck.

Comment: @xxx I have deleted my comment mentioning your original name. But please refrain from vandalizing the question or my answer. You asked the question and can't take it back.

Comment: @xxx you may be interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post

Answer (score 3):

1. > $Tag = MAC_k(\Sigma_i m_i)$.

   Too many attacks to enumerate. As long as the sum over the blocks remains the same, the tag remains valid. If the sum is reduced modulo $2^{\mathrm{blocksize}}$ at the end, the attacker can choose the whole message, apart from a single block used to balance the sum.
2. > $t_i = MAC_k(m_i)$ and $Tag = (t_1, ..., t_l)$.

   Reordering message blocks and tag blocks in the same way results in a valid (message,tag pair). You can duplicate blocks. In general, the attacker can compose a message from any block that has appeared in a valid authenticated message.
3. > $t_i = MAC_k(i||m_i)$ where $i$ is a sequence number and $Tag = (t_1, ..., t_l)$.

   Reordering is not possible. If you authenticate several messages an attacker can pick each block from a different messages.

   Another attack is simply truncating both message and tag to $l^\prime<l$ blocks.